# Narrow down type-hint of return value to child class if function only hints to parent class

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-3.10, pyright

I have an external function that works like a factory and returns instances of different classes with a common parent type:
e.g.

```py
class Printer:
    def make(self, blueprint:str) -> Blueprint: ...

class PrintA(Blueprint): 
     def a_specific(self) -> int: ...

class PrintB(Blueprint):
     def b_specific(self, args):
         """docstring"""

a : PrintA = Printer().make("A")
b : PrintB = Printer().make("B")
# TypeHint: "(variable) a: Blueprint"
# TypeHint: "(variable) b: Blueprint"

# Usage:
result = a.a_specific() # function & type of result not detected : Any
b.b_specific(arg) # function not detected, parameters and description unknown : Any
```

The problem is that `a` and `b` have `Blueprint` as their given type hint.
**How can I force the correct type hint onto the variables**, so that the child functions can be detected by my IDE?

---

I tried to use `# type: ignore[override]` but that does not seem applicable for this purpose as its no error; is there by chance another magic comment command to indicate that the type checker should trust the human annotation?

---

Notes: I cannot adjust Printer or the Blueprints itself. Modify a matching `*.pyi` file is possible but should be minimal.
The amount of Blueprints is large.

Not sure if relevant but using VS-Code and Python Extension for type hinting.

At least in my example PrintA and PrintB cannot be instantiated directly via Python and `Printer` has to be used to initialize them.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is your goal? Maybe `Generic` should be used here, but i'm not sure what is the desired behaviour you are trying to get

Comment: Slightly extended the exampled. The problem is that `a` and `b` have specific functions. Type-hinting and Pylint(?) cannot detect these functions and leaving me with a lot of functions afterwards where the signature are unknown for my IDE.

Comment: With `assert isinstance(a, PrintA)` you can narrow the type from `Blueprint` to `PrintA`

Comment: asserting seems not super nice & straightforward to me but does the job. Thank you!

Comment: How exactly is the `blueprint` argument used by `Printer.make`? If it's just a proxy for a subclass of `Blueprint`, it should probably just take the subclass directly. Nothing about the *types* of your functions provides any way to link `make("A")` to an instance of `PrintA`.

Comment: `a : PrintA = Printer().make("A")` should fail to type-check, because the stated return type `Blueprint` is not consistent with the hinted type `PrintA`.

Comment: You might be able to modify a `.pyi` file to define a bunch of overloads for `Printer.make`, e.g., `@overload def make(self, blueprint: LiteralStr["A"]) -> PrintA`, `@overload def make(self, blueprint: LiteralStr["B") -> PrintB`, etc. Then as long as the argument to `Printer().make` *is* a literal string, the correct type for `a` and `b` can be inferred.

Comment: @chepner In my example Printer.make is a C++ function and the string `blueprint` selects one of many possible classes that are then returned by it. The majority (if not all) classes cannot be instantiated from python, directly using them is not possible. Currently I only need very small selection of them. So overloading is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible method that helps static type checkers is type casting using `typing.cast`:

```
from typing import cast

a = cast(PrintA, Printer().make("A"))
b = cast(PrintB, Printer().make("B"))
```

The IDE and static type checkers should now recognize `a` and `b` correctly.

Unlike assertions, there is no runtime check to ensure the cast is accurate, so be careful.

Comment: For someone not aware what this function does it might look a bit strange. I kind of hoped for a magic comment, however if, or as long there is none, `cast` is imo probably the purest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can at least change the type hints for `Printer` in a `pyi` file, you can overload `Printer.make` to have argument-specific return types.

```
from typing import overload, Literal


class Printer:

    @overload
    def make(self, blueprint: Literal["A"]) -> PrintA:
        ...

    @overload
    def make(self, blueprint: Literal["B"]) -> PrintB:
        ...

    # etc
```

But this requires the argument to `make` be an appropriate literal; you can't use, for example, arbitrary user input that happens to have an expected value at *runtime*.

Now the following should work

```
a = Printer().make("A")  # reveal_type(a) == PrintA
x: Literal["B"] = "B"
b = Printer().make(x)  # reveal_type(b) == PrintB
```

For non-literal arguments, you'll need some redundant-looking code in order to pass *static* type-checking. For example, a `match` statement could be used to narrow the static type of a dynamically generated string `x`:

```
x = input()  # reveal_type(x) is str
match x:
    case "A":
        # reveal_type(x) is Literal['A']
        Printer().make(x).a_specific()
    case "B":
        # reveal_type(x) is Literal['B']
        Printer().make(x).b_specific()
    case _:
        raise ValueError(f"No known blueprint type {x}")
```

Something like

```
x = input()  # say "A" is entered
# magic to infer static type of PrintA for c???
c = Printer().make(x)
```

is right out, because you can't statically determine the value of `c`. Note the `match` statement above only uses the value of `Printer().make(x)` within the context where the static type of `x` is known. You can't assign to `c` in each branch and expect the static type of `c` to be known outside the `match` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to stop using `Printer.make` directly, I suspect you could use a properly generic wrapper instead. Something like

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Blueprint)

def printer_make(p: Printer, blueprint: T) -> T:
    return p.make({ PrintA: "A", PrintB: "B", ...})


p = Printer()
a = printer_make(p, PrintA)  # reveal_type(a) == PrintA
```